# Returning arrays of different lengths in a Tensorflow dataset pipeline

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm doing object detection using Tensorflow in python.

I want to use tensorflow input pipeline for loading batches of input data.
The thing is that there is a variable number of objects in images.

Imagine I want to do something following. *annotations* is an array of image filenames and bounding boxes which it contains. Labels are excluded. Each bounding box is represented by four numbers.

```
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function()
def prepare_sample(annotation):
    annotation_parts = tf.strings.split(annotation, sep=' ')
    image_file_name = annotation_parts[0]
    image_file_path = tf.strings.join(["/images/", image_file_name])
    depth_image = tf.io.read_file(image_file_path)
    bboxes = tf.reshape(annotation_parts[1:], shape=[-1,4])
    return depth_image, bboxes

annotations = ['image1.png 1 2 3 4', 'image2.png 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8']
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(annotations)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(annotations))
dataset = dataset.map(prepare_sample)
dataset = dataset.batch(16)

for image, bboxes in dataset:
  pass
```

In the example above, image1 contains a single object, whereas image2 contains two objects.
I receive the following error:

> InvalidArgumentError: Cannot add tensor to the batch: number of
> elements does not match. Shapes are: [tensor]: [1,4], [batch]: [2,4]

That makes sense. **I'm looking for ways to return arrays of different lengths from the mapped function.** What can I do?

Thank you!

EDIT:
I think I found the solution; I don't receive the error anymore.
I changed `dataset.batch(16)` to `dataset.padded_batch(16)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering solution here for the benefit of the community, since the author of this post @Ladislav Ondris is able to solve the issue.

The error will be resolved after changing `dataset.batch(16)` to `dataset.padded_batch(16)`.

Below is the modified code of the same.

```
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function()
def prepare_sample(annotation):
    annotation_parts = tf.strings.split(annotation, sep=' ')
    image_file_name = annotation_parts[0]
    image_file_path = tf.strings.join(["/images/", image_file_name])
    depth_image = tf.io.read_file(image_file_path)
    bboxes = tf.reshape(annotation_parts[1:], shape=[-1,4])
    return depth_image, bboxes

annotations = ['image1.png 1 2 3 4', 'image2.png 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8']
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(annotations)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(annotations))
dataset = dataset.map(prepare_sample)
dataset = dataset.padded_batch(16)

for image, bboxes in dataset:
  pass
```